# Strapi:How Restrict user (non-admin) to access his data only

Tags: node.js, strapi

I'm using strapi.
User registered with local api getting all data same as super admin.
How to implement or which plugin setting restricts, non-admin user to access data that he has added. (Similar to author-admin role)

Answer (score 0):

This depends. Do you mean access their own data via the default Strapi backend? if yes, you could give them the Author role. Authors can always onle edit their own content.

If you mean access via REST API, you should be able to accomplish this with a [policy](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/policies.html), where you can restrict specific access based on your code entirely.